# How to convince GHC about type equality on a recursive type

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, singleton-type

I'm defining a type whose type parameters have some relations. I have `Item` type which takes `Cat` and `SubCat`, but you can use some of the types of `SubCat` depending on `Cat`. For example, when you specify `Cat1` as `Cat`, you can specify `SubCat1` or `SubCat2` as `SubCat`.

I implemented it using `ValidSubCats` type family to define valid `SubCat`s for each `Cat`, and `OneOf` type family to define a constraint.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, PolyKinds, StandaloneKindSignatures, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Kind (Constraint, Type)
import Data.Type.Equality ((:~:)(..), TestEquality(..))
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

data Cat = Cat1 | Cat2
type SCat :: Cat -> Type
data SCat cat where
    SCat1 :: SCat 'Cat1
    SCat2 :: SCat 'Cat2

data SubCat = SubCat1 | SubCat2 | SubCat3
type SSubCat :: SubCat -> Type
data SSubCat subCat where
    SSubCat1 :: SSubCat 'SubCat1
    SSubCat2 :: SSubCat 'SubCat2
    SSubCat3 :: SSubCat 'SubCat3

type ValidSubCats :: Cat -> [SubCat]
type family ValidSubCats cat where
    ValidSubCats 'Cat1 = '[ 'SubCat1, 'SubCat2 ]
    ValidSubCats 'Cat2 = '[ 'SubCat2, 'SubCat3 ]

type OneOf :: k -> [k] -> Constraint
type family OneOf t ts where
    OneOf t (t ': _) = ()
    OneOf t (_ ': ts) = OneOf t ts
    OneOf _ _ = ('True ~ 'False)

type Item :: Cat -> SubCat -> Type
data Item cat subCat where
    Item :: OneOf subCat (ValidSubCats cat) => Item cat subCat
```

Now, I'm trying to define a function to create an `Item` from `SCat` and `SSubCat`.

```
type HL :: (k -> Type) -> [k] -> Type
data HL f t where
    HCons :: f t -> HL f ts -> HL f (t ': ts)
    HNil :: HL f '[]
infixr 5 `HCons`

validSSubCats :: SCat cat -> HL SSubCat (ValidSubCats cat)
validSSubCats SCat1 = SSubCat1 `HCons` SSubCat2 `HCons` HNil
validSSubCats SCat2 = SSubCat2 `HCons` SSubCat3 `HCons` HNil

instance TestEquality SSubCat where
    testEquality SSubCat1 SSubCat1 = Just Refl
    testEquality SSubCat2 SSubCat2 = Just Refl
    testEquality SSubCat3 SSubCat3 = Just Refl
    testEquality _ _ = Nothing

oneOf :: TestEquality f => f t -> HL f ts -> Maybe (OneOf t ts :~: (() :: Constraint))
oneOf x (HCons y ys) = case testEquality x y of
                           Just Refl -> Just Refl
                           Nothing -> unsafeCoerce $ oneOf x ys
oneOf _ HNil = Nothing

makeItem :: SCat cat -> SSubCat subCat -> Maybe (Item cat subCat)
makeItem sCat sSubCat = case oneOf sSubCat (validSSubCats sCat) of
                            Just Refl -> Just Item
                            Nothing -> Nothing
```

But as you can see, I'm using `unsafeCoerce` to define `oneOf`. I got this error when I removed it.

```
test.hs:54:39: error:
    • Could not deduce: OneOf t ts1 ~ OneOf t (t1 : ts1)
      from the context: ts ~ (t1 : ts1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   HCons :: forall {k} (f :: k -> *) (t :: k) (ts :: [k]).
                            f t -> HL f ts -> HL f (t : ts),
                 in an equation for ‘oneOf’
        at q.hs:52:10-19
      Expected: Maybe (OneOf t ts :~: (() :: Constraint))
        Actual: Maybe (OneOf t ts1 :~: (() :: Constraint))
      NB: ‘OneOf’ is a non-injective type family
    • In the expression: oneOf x ys
      In a case alternative: Nothing -> oneOf x ys
      In the expression:
        case testEquality x y of
          Just Refl -> Just Refl
          Nothing -> oneOf x ys
    • Relevant bindings include
        ys :: HL f ts1 (bound at q.hs:52:18)
        y :: f t1 (bound at q.hs:52:16)
        x :: f t (bound at q.hs:52:7)
        oneOf :: f t
                 -> HL f ts -> Maybe (OneOf t ts :~: (() :: Constraint))
          (bound at q.hs:52:1)
   |
54 |                            Nothing -> oneOf x ys
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I convince GHC that it can infer `OneOf t (t ': ts) :~: (() :: Constraint)` from `OneOf t ts :~: (() :: Constraint)` without using `unsafeCoerce`?

Comment: One way may be to redefine `OneOf` using `Data.Type.Equality.==`. See also https://blog.poisson.chat/posts/2018-06-06-hlists-dependent-haskell.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using something which has a value-level representation, since we can directly manipulate such things more easily. This is often easier to work with in general. For example:

```
data OneOf' t ts where
  Here :: forall t ts. OneOf' t (t ': ts)
  There :: forall t t2 ts. OneOf' t ts -> OneOf' t (t2 ': ts)

oneOf' :: TestEquality f => f t -> HL f ts -> Maybe (OneOf' t ts)
oneOf' _ HNil = Nothing
oneOf' x (HCons y ys) =
  case testEquality x y of
    Just Refl -> Just Here
    Nothing -> There <$> oneOf' x ys
```

This does not directly answer the question as asked, although if you can write a function with type

```
convertOneOf :: forall t ts. OneOf' t ts -> (OneOf t ts :~: (() :: Constraint))
```

then it would answer the exact question. Right now, I'm not sure how to do this (or even whether it is possible). I think you need an auxiliary function

```
weakenOneOf :: forall t t2 ts. OneOfTrue t ts -> OneOfTrue t (t2 ': ts)
```

(where I've used the synonym `OneOfTrue` to make things easier to read: `type OneOfTrue t ts = OneOf t ts :~: (() :: Constraint)`).

If this can be implemented then you should be good to go, although I would probably still prefer to use `OneOf'` when possible.

It's worth noting that something like `OneOf'` is a relatively common construct in dependently typed languages: There's an Agda example [here](https://plfa.github.io/Lists/#any), an Idris example [here](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/idris2/current/base_docs/docs/Data.List.Elem.html) and a similar thing in Coq [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html#In). Each of these has value-level content in the same way that `OneOf'` does.

`Item` could be rewritten to use `OneOf'` like this:

```
type Item' :: Cat -> SubCat -> Type
data Item' cat subCat where
    Item' :: OneOf' subCat (ValidSubCats cat) -> Item' cat subCat
```

and there is a corresponding rewrite for `makeItem` to use `Item'`.

## Why the original `OneOf` is tricky and `OneOf'` is less tricky

It is often difficult to work with something like `OneOf`. One reason is that Haskell allows type families which can get "stuck". This prevents can prevent some type-level "reductions" and we do not have things like canonical forms.

For example, consider this definition which could be useful in dealing with something like type-level lists passed to a `OneOf`:

```
listDecideNilCons :: forall ts. Either (ts :~: '[]) (IsCons ts)
listDecideNilCons = ...

data IsCons a where
  MkIsCons :: forall t ts. IsCons (t ': ts)
```

`listDecideNilCons` would just tell you that a type-level list is either a nil or a cons, which seems pretty reasonable and it would be a handy fact to make use of. In fact, I suspect that it would be *necessary* to be able to implement `listDecideNilCons` or something similar to it in order to be able to implement `convertOneOf`. I suspect even more strongly that it is necessary to implement the other direction of the conversion.

However, the existence of stuck type families is sufficient to show that `listDecideNilCons` cannot be implemented. Consider:

```
type family Sticky (b :: Bool) :: [Int] where
  Sticky True = '[]

example :: Either ((Sticky False) :~: '[]) (IsCons (Sticky False))
example = listDecideNilCons
```

This code type-checks. What should the value of `example` be? Since `Sticky False` cannot be reduced any further, there isn't a value for `example` that would make sense.

Note that if we also have *value*-level information, like we do with `OneOf'`, we do not run into this issue for two reasons: Stuck types are not an issue because we can control which specific "shapes" (like `'[]` and `... ': ...`) we are allowed to take in and we can use the proof values when we construct proofs of new things.

For example, in the case of `OneOf'`, it *ensures* that the type-level list will have the "shape" `... ': ...`. In the function `oneOf'`, we are using the proof value from the recursive call `oneOf' x ys` to build a larger proof.

In the original `oneOf` function, we cannot make use of the fact that the result of a recursive call will either have a "cons shape" or it will give back `Nothing` (since the original `OneOf` doesn't give us this information). However, we *must* know this to use the result of the recursive call to produce the desired result since the original `OneOf` *requires* a "cons shape".

Comment: Although I don't think I've fully understood it, I at least got where I have to look into. Thank you for the detailed answer.